# Switch table names based on condition using mysql

Tags: mysql

In my project, i have 3 tables

- productTable (pid, pName, descId)
- descTable (descId, description)
- centralDescTable (descId, description).

If (descId from productTable contains "c") then fetch description from centralDescTable
 else, 
fetch from descTable.

how can i write if condition in mysql query?

Answer (score 1):

Try a LEFT JOIN with both tables and use COALESCE to get the given description.

```
select p.*, coalesce(c.description, d.description)
from productTable 
left join descTable d        on d.descId = p.descId
left join centralDescTable c on c.descId = p.descId
```